# How do we give charity during this pandemic?

Tags: ramadan, sadaqah

We are in the month of Ramadan which means we need to give more charity.

I am finding it difficult to give charity because during this pandemic (the virus) it is not advisable to go outside (and everything is shut).

So how can I give charity? I can't do it online (for reasons I cannot list here).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many Islamic ways for giving charity through banking channels , online and through charity organizations.

Answer (score 0):

How about making extra food at iftar and giving some for your neighbours ? 
It’s a nice gesture that will cheer people up as well and show people that Muslims care about there neighbours as we should.
(You can leave it on the doorstep and leave a note) 
Some of your neighbours may be struggling due to loosing there jobs etc And not be able to afford a meal every day.
Or shopping for a vulnerable person local to you.

But If you can’t do it online there may be a way to do it over the phone.